# How to configure getItemLayout prop for SectionList with dynamic height?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I'm using RN 0.62.2 but when I try to use SectionList with more than 4000 rows with different heights each and I try to use the `scrollToIndex` method, I get the error:

> Invariant Violation: scrollToIndex should be used in conjunction with getItemLayout or onScrollToIndexFailed, otherwise there is no way to know the location of offscreen indices or handle failures.

I've done some research and realized that I should be using the `getItemLayout` prop to tell the list its size and be able to recognize exactly where I'm jumping to, but I've browsed several forums and can't find the correct way to use it, I've treated using the NPM libraries: react-native-section-list-get-item-layout and `sectionlist-get-itemlayout` following the guide of this [link](https://medium.com/@jsoendermann/sectionlist-and-getitemlayout-2293b0b916fb)
but I still can't find a way to get my `sectionlist` to work, please help. Thank you very much in advance.

My code is:

```js
function Catalog({ navigation, route }) {

    const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {

        async function getProducts() {
            const result = await API.getProducts(route.params.id);
            setProducts(result);
        }
        getProducts();
    }, [])

    _getItemLayout = sectionListGetItemLayout({
        // The height of the row with rowData at the given sectionIndex and rowIndex
        getItemHeight: (rowData, sectionIndex, rowIndex) => sectionIndex === 0 ? 100 : 50,
   
        // These five properties are optional
        getSeparatorHeight: () => 1, // The height of your separators between items
        getSectionHeaderHeight: () => 66.5, // The height of your section headers
        getSectionFooterHeight: () => 0, // The height of your section footers
        listHeaderHeight: 0, // The height of your header
        listFooterHeight: 0, // The height of your footer
      });

     renderEmpty = () => <Empty text="Cargando productos..." />

    renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <Product title={item.title} {...item} />
    )

    renderTab = ({ title, isActive }) => (
        <View
            style={[
                styles.tabContainer,
                { borderBottomWidth: isActive ? 2 : 0 }
            ]}
        >
            <Text
                style={[
                    styles.tabText,
                    { color: isActive ? '#d00000' : '#56555a' }
                ]}
            >
                {title.toUpperCase()}
            </Text>
        </View>
    )

    return (
        <View style={styles.container} >
            <View style={styles.banners}>
                <Slider horizontal={true} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.list}>
               <SectionList
                    sections={products}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.title}
                    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
                    //scrollToLocationOffset={100}
                    //initialNumToRender={100}
                    //removeClippedSubviews={true}
                    tabBarStyle={styles.tabBar}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={styles.separator} />}
                    ListEmptyComponent={renderEmpty}
                    renderTab={renderTab}
                    renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (<CategoryListLayout style={styles.header} title={section.title} />)}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    getItemLayout={this._getItemLayout}

                />
            </View>
        </View>    
    );
}
export default Catalog
```

Comment: Hello there, did you ever find  a solution? I think I am in the same boat .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67338792/how-do-i-use-the-getitemlayout-prop-for-flatlist-in-react-native